# Почему System.in объект ввода?

Tags: java, терминология

Для чтения символа с клавиатуры достаточно вызвать метод `System.in.read()`, где `System. in` - объект ввода (с клавиатуры), дополняющий объект вывода `System.out`.

Давайте разберемся:
`System.in.read()` - `System` это класс, `in` это переменная-константа, `read()` - это метод. Хотелось бы спросить почему в книге написано вот так:

> Для чтения символа с клавиатуры достаточно вызвать метод
>   System.in.read(), где System. in - объект ввода (с клавиатуры)

Почему `System.in` объект ввода? Почему не написано что за "входящий поток" отвечает константа `in` класса `System`, а написано что это объект ввода?
Просто под объектом я представляю экземпляр класса, то есть аля:

```
System systemObj = new System();
```

Где `systemObj` является объектом. Можно по подробнее?

Comment: Объясните где вы берете такие полезные и хорошие вопросы? Я слежу за вами и ваши вопросы как мёд на душу. Всегда прокачиваюсь от них, потому что они необычные и как я увидел глубокие.

Comment: @PetrVanovsky книги каждый день читаю и сразу практикуюсь, а что не понятно пишу сюда параллельно делая задания на работе, но задания рутинные. Но пока не получу опыта, интересных и хороших проектов не получу, поэтому сижу просто нонстопом учусь, трудно, но, а кому сейчас легко? Вот и всё .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Любая переменная/поле в Java - это либо примитив, либо null, либо экземпляр какого-то класса. Третьего не дано. Очевидно, что `System.in` не является ни примитивом, ни null. Значит, это экземпляр какого-то класса.

Более точно, это экземпляр класса `FileInputStream`. Потому что в современных ОС потоки стандартного ввода-вывода ведут себя как предварительно открытые файлы. Создать аналогичный объект вы можете самостоятельно вот так:

```
InputStream myIn = new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in);
```

Answer (score 7):

Потому что "входящий поток" - это тоже объект. Если открыть [исходный код System](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#l83), то можно увидеть, что `in` - это переменная типа [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). То есть в рантайме в ней хранится **объект** класса `InputStream`.

Comment: InputStream это же класс, а не экземпляр класса?

Comment: Да, это класс. Но ниже по коду, в методе `setIn`, переменной `in` присваивается экземпляр этого класса. Не думаете же вы, что вызываете метод `read` переменной хранящей `null`?

Comment: [Ссылка](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#l150) на строку метода осуществляющего инициализацию переменной. Само присваивание происходит ["глубже" в виртуальной машине](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/System.c#l427), где код уже Сишный.